# How to get the phone number of an android phone via adb?

Tags: android, adb

Is there a way to get the phone number of a phone over adb?

I looked at dumpsys as a likely answer, but none of the system services seem to keep track of the phone's own number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`iphonesubinfo` service "keeps track" of the subscriber information including phone numbers. Unfortunately `iphonesubinfo` service does not implement the `dump()` method so dumpsys shows nothing. You will have to use `service call` command to call `IPhoneSubInfo.getLine1Number()` or `IPhoneSubInfo.getMsisdn()` instead

Depending on the android version and your carrier one or two of the following commands will tell you the phone number (`service call` commands require `root` privileges):

```
service call iphonesubinfo 4
service call iphonesubinfo 5
service call iphonesubinfo 6
service call iphonesubinfo 7
service call iphonesubinfo 8
```

If you want to find out the proper code for your specific device - download the script from [Calling Android services from ADB shell](http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/calling-android-services-from-adb-shell.html) post and run it like this:

```
./get_android_service_call_numbers.sh iphonesubinfo | grep getLine1Number
```

**UPDATE**

Transaction codes for Android 5.0:

```
service call iphonesubinfo 11 # getLine1Number()
service call iphonesubinfo 15 # getMsisdn()
```

Transaction codes for Android 5.1:

```
service call iphonesubinfo 13 # getLine1Number()
service call iphonesubinfo 17 # getMsisdn()
```

Comment: Awesome. This worked for my device. Unfortunately the result is ugly and will require some heavy parsing, but it works!

Comment: Does not seem to work without rooting the phone. In all cases I get an error message.

Comment: For what it's worth, in the current API (19), `iphonesubinfo` does implement a `dump()` method.  However, it only reports Phone Type (e.g., GSM) and Device ID (e.g., IMEI), not the phone number.  Helps if you're interested in one of those, otherwise, keep using the above.

Comment: Also, The codes above correspond to the following `iphonesubinfo` service transactions: 4 = `getGroupIdLevel1`, 5 = `getIccSerialNumber`, 6 = `getLine1Number`, 7 = `getLine1AlphaTag`, and 8 = `getMsisdn`.

Comment: I'm ran this on Samsung S4 (unrooted). The output (after a lot of parsing of course) looks like this:
`iRequires READ_PHONE_STATE: N either user 2000 nor current process has android permissionREAD_PHONE_STATE`.
I've USB Debugging turned ON.

Answer (score 1):

#### Android 13

Here's a command that can be used to retrieve the phone number:

```bash
adb shell 'service call iphonesubinfo 19' \
    | awk -F "'" '{print $2}' \
    | tr -d '\n' \
    | sed 's/\s\+/\n/g' \
    | tr -d '.' \
    | awk '{if ($0) print $0; else print "No phone number found"}'
```

1. `adb shell 'service call iphonesubinfo 19'`: This command invokes the `service call iphonesubinfo 19` service call in the Android shell. It retrieves information related to the phone, including the phone number.
2. `awk -F "'" '{print $2}'`: The `awk` command is used to process the output of the previous step. It splits each line of the output based on the single quote delimiter (`'`) and prints the second field, which contains the phone number.
3. `tr -d '\n'`: The `tr` command is used to remove any newline characters from the output. This ensures that the phone number is presented as a single line of text.
4. `sed 's/\s\+/\n/g'`: The `sed` command is used to replace consecutive whitespace characters with newline characters (`\n`). This results in the phone number being printed on a separate line.
5. `tr -d '.'`: The `tr` command is used to delete any dots (`.`) from the phone number. Dots are sometimes included in the output, and this step removes them.
6. `awk '{ if ($0 == "") print "No phone number found"; else print }'`: This `awk` command checks if the phone number is empty. If it is empty, it prints the message "No phone number found". Otherwise, it prints the phone number.