# Check phone number from adb shell

Tags: android, adb

One way of getting a phone number via the shell would be to dial anther phone using the

```
service call phone
```

Is there a way I could get the phone number using the adb shell on a rooted phone without having to call out?

For example, a scenario would be a pre-paid sim which has no balance, hence cannot call out. Therefore using a service to call would not work

Comment: sorry about that, i tried searching for it earlier but couldn't find it. Thanks!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200788/how-to-get-the-phone-number-of-an-android-phone-via-adb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked in my case: Nexus 5 rooted phone.

```
service call iphonesubinfo 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked on my un-rooted Galaxy S3. 
Dumping the phone state seems to take a little while (couple of minutes) so be patient.

Open a terminal in the sdk/platform-tools directory

```
./adb shell dumpstate | grep 'Line 1'
```

here is the list of "other" adb shell commands , documented in the developer guide, which can be found here -> http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#shellcommands

```
Other shell commands

For a list of all the available shell programs, use the following command:

adb shell ls /system/bin
Help is available for most of the commands.

Table 5 lists some of the more common adb shell commands.

Table 5. Some other adb shell commands
Shell Command   Description Comments
dumpsys Dumps system data to the screen.    The Dalvik Debug Monitor Server (DDMS) tool offers integrated debug environment that you may find easier to use.
dumpstate   Dumps state to a file.
logcat [option]... [filter-spec]... Enables system and app logging and prints output to the screen.
dmesg   Prints kernel debugging messages to the screen.
start   Starts (restarts) an emulator/device instance.   
stop    Stops execution of an emulator/device instance.
```

Comment: No unfortunately that didn't work for me.

127|root@hammerhead:/ # dumpstate | grep 'Line 1'                              
warning: timed out dumping pid 833
warning: could not create process interface for 12316
warning: could not create process interface for 12337
1|root@hammerhead:/ #

Comment: so are you saying that  adb shell dumpstate does not work on your device?

Comment: I guess you need to try to just get ./adb shell dumpstate to work first, it is a standard  adb shell command, if you can't get that to run then you have other problems

Comment: `./adb shell dumpstate` printed a lot of info - phone number isn't one of them

Comment: dumpstate itself works but grepping it times out

Comment: it does take a while so you can try to dump it to a file and then grep the file once it is done.  It's weird that it takes so long to dump the state, but it happens on mine as well. I hope it's it there for you, it could be device dependent ... the idea was based on my use of http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number() , but apparently this does not work 100% of the time.

Comment: @Manu , I am guessing getLine1Number() from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number() would return null on your device if you tried.  There does not seem to be a 100% clean way to get a device phone number via the api.