# Android phone number via ADB

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to retrieve the Android phone number via ADB.
I have tried:

```
adb shell dumpstate | grep Msisdn=
```

it works but takes several minutes to get the result.
Is there a faster way to retrieve the phone number?

I have read and tried the question/answer:
[How to get the phone number of an android phone via adb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200788/how-to-get-the-phone-number-of-an-android-phone-via-adb)

but it did not work for me.
I have a Samsung S5 Android Lollipop 5.0

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex, I have read and tried it but it did not work for me.
I have a Samsung Android Lollipop 5.0

Comment: There is no easy and universal way.

Comment: Thanks Alex, maybe someone out there has an answer. I am wondering if there is a dump for SIM CARD info that contains this information.