# How to get the phone number programatically from a new SIM card?

Tags: android

I can get the phone number from some old SIM card by using `TelephonyManager.getLine1Number()`, but it's not working for some new SIM card. 
I tried to use this code snippet, but it's also not working.  It just return empty string.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    List<SubscriptionInfo> subscription = SubscriptionManager.from(getApplicationContext()).getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
    for (int i = 0; i < subscription.size(); i++) {
        SubscriptionInfo info = subscription.get(i);
        Log.d(TAG, "number " + info.getNumber());
    }
}
```

Is there another way to know the phone number programmatically, I even think to send a real SMS to another device, and this device can receive and get the phone number and send to server backend. But it's a bit troublesome, is there any simpler solution?

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200788/how-to-get-the-phone-number-of-an-android-phone-via-adb

Comment: ADB is not programatical way, I cannot connect to ADB, because I may even dont have contact to the device.

Comment: There is no other reliable way to get the number alike that. It may even report zeros.

Comment: I have no specific knowledge of getting phone numbers in Android, but two questions come to mind: **(a)** were the old SIM (working) and the new SIM (not working) both  tested in exactly the same phone? If different phones, it could be the HW or version of Android that's the problem. **(b)** to help people who might no more than I, can you expand on "_it's also not working_"? An empty string? Error messages / exceptions? Anything in logcat?

Comment: I tested on the same device, only the SIM card different, the android system is 8.1. From Android System Setting->About phone->Phone number, I can see old one has phone number, another one don't have.

Comment: If i not forget that About phone->Phone number must be set manually.

Comment: No, the old SIM card number appears automactially, no manual step required.